# Passing object from Parse query to UIContainerView from Parent View

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have the following navigation stack: Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> UIContainer (embedded into the View Controller).

[image]

On the viewDidLoad() of the View Controller I am querying Parse to get back a User.

The query returns a var userFound = User(), how can I pass this User object to the UIContainerView?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working for anyone that might need it.

With the following:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("theViewController") as! TheViewController

controller.userDetails = userFound

self.addChildViewController(controller)                   
self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
self.didMoveToParentViewController(controller)
```

Thanks